# How do I prevent re-render while using infinite scroll in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I am fetching data in React, I am fetching users, so I have a state (I am using redux) allUsers, in which I am storing fetched users and adding more users with infinite scroll once scrollbar reaches the bottom. The problem is that when new data is being added to the allUsers state, React is re-rendering all of the users because I am using .map to render them. Could you please tell me how to fix that? Here is the code:

```
    const allUsers = useSelector(state => state.setAllUsersReducer);
    const page = useSelector(state => state.setPageReducer);
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.setLoadingReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

    const fetchAllUsers = () => {
        console.log(page)
       fetch(`${url}/${page}/15`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(setAllUsers(data.list))
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('Error message: ', err))
    }

    console.log(allUsers)

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchAllUsers();
    }, [page])

    const handleScroll = () => {
        dispatch(setPage());
    }

    window.onscroll = function () {
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            handleScroll();
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="allUsersList">
            {
                allUsers.length > 0 ? (
                    allUsers.map((user, index) => (
                        <User key={index + 1} name={user.name} lastName={user.lastName} prefix={user.prefix} title={user.title} img={user.imageUrl}/>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div> Loading... </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You just have to use `React.memo` on the `User` component and the keys can be `id`s if available

Comment: @RameshReddy thank you very much! I will try it now

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes, it worked, once again thank you so much, it was super helpful